# Gridview row having multiple record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a stored procedure that retrieves employee information - I don’t want to edit this stored procedure because it is globally use with in the website.

Here is now my dilemma, how can I put multiple row records in a column in the grid view. Is Gridview powerful enough to my scenario below or I really need to edit the stored procedure or my copy of it. Thanks

Records retrieve by stored procedure

```
Employee_ID    Purchase ID   Amount 
    1           0123456       100
    1           012356        560
    1           012446        560
    1           012126        560
    2           011122        100
    2           051122        200
```

I want to achieve this in gridview

```
Employee ID    Purchase ID    Total Amount
-----------------------------------------
    1           012345           1780
                012346         
                012446 
                012126         
    2           011122           3000
                051122
```

Comment: Its not very clear to me what do the numbers mean. Is 1780 the total amount? What is 012346 and the numbers below that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new stored procedure for use with this gridview only, leaving your existing stored procedure as-is so it doesn't break other parts of your code.

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a new stored procedure, you could sum the totals in your vb code, although it will be more work than doing it at the DB level.  You'd do this using the gridview's datasource, not the gridview itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a template column, and start it with (I believe) an  `</td></tr><tr><td>`

In any case, each gridview template column implicitly (you can't see it) renders open/close td tags around whatever you put in it.